# Rails Send boolean to serializer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.1

This is my comment controller

```
  def find
    post_id = params['id'];
    @comments = Comment.where('post_id = ?',job_id)

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @comments,root: false  }
    end
```

and this is my comment model

```
    class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
        attr_accessible :user,:comment
        belongs_to :post
def comments
        if self.comment.eql?(0)
            return false
        else
            return true
        end
    end
```

And here in my comment serializer

```
    class CommentSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
        attributes :id,:user,:comment,:created_at,:is_comments

def is_comments
    object.comments
end
```

The above code shows nothing

I need to use this serialized value in ember's model

Comment: i dont understand , what stopping you from doing this ? looking at the documention here https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers , i see that it can be easily done. whats issue are you facing exactly?

Answer (score 0):

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
      attr_accessible :user,:comment
      belongs_to :post
      def comments
         self.comment
      end
end
```

Here is the serializer which can be used as a boolean in emberjs

```
def is_comments
   if !object.comments.blank?
      return true
   end
end
```

Comment: Wow!great idea! Asking question with your own answer.. :D